# I can't manage to send messages in C

Tags: c, message, system-calls

I'm writing this script in order to practice in sending messages in c with mq_send() & mq_receive() system calls but i'm stuck here. I can't manage to get any output from this simple code.
I tried to define the attr struct but nothing changed.
Can someone help me?

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define Q "/queue"
#define SIZE 1024

int main(){
    mqd_t qd_w;
    mqd_t qd_r = mq_open(Q,O_CREAT|O_RDONLY, 0660, NULL);

    
    pid_t pid = fork();

    //son
    if(pid == 0){
        char str_w[] = "ciaoooo";
        //scanf("%s",str_w);
        qd_w = mq_open(Q, O_WRONLY, 0660, NULL);
        mq_send(qd_w, (const char*)str_w, strlen(str_w),0);
        mq_close(qd_w);
        exit(0);
    }else{

        //parent    
        wait(NULL);
        char* str_r = malloc(sizeof(char)*SIZE);
        mq_receive(qd_r, str_r, sizeof(char)*SIZE, NULL);
        printf("%s \n", str_r);
        mq_close(qd_r);
        mq_unlink(Q);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Step 1 is to check the return value of all the system calls you're making.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Not related to receiving but this causes undefined behaviour: `printf("%s \n", str_r);` `str_r` is not a string as you do not send the terminating 0 byte and also do not add one after receiving.

Comment: You should apply proper indentation to your code to increase readability.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If it's your first post, please thoroughly read [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If you had printed out the return value of receive, you would see it fails on EMSGSIZE.

If you check the man pages (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_receive.3.html), you will see what this error means:

> ```
>   EMSGSIZE
>          msg_len was less than the mq_msgsize attribute of the
>          message queue.
> ```

What is the mq_msgsize of the message queue if you did not specify any attributes?
You can either check it using `mq_getattr`, or just trust my word that it is 8K.

The message size you use is 1024. Try changing it to 8192 and your code will work.

P.S: as the guys mentioned in comments, your code has other problems - you don't check return values, you don't validate string NULL termination after reading a message, and you really should fix your indentation. But that is unrelated to your question, just take a note.